# database optimization

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I am using PHP and MySQL with IIS server. My site speed performance is very poor. Can someone suggest me good database optimization and query optimization techniques? This site has heavy traffic and big database.

Comment: @diEcho is right. And how do you know database performance is your problem, and not web server or web application code performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you would like to optimize. (I'm amusing your using PHP but this can pretty much apply to all the languages).

You could try to make your queries more efficient so you make less calls to the server during each request.

You could also try to use caching, for example - http://memcached.org/ . So you don't have to call the database/files to construct a page on each request, you just simply pull it out of the cache.

And one article I liked was - http://20bits.com/articles/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck/ - maybe it can help you too.

Comment: i already read 20bits.com and i apply all rules. i cant understand what is problem. i use indexes, tight up data structure but no efficient result

Answer (score 3):

- Check the indexes on your database.

If you join, make sure you can use an index. If you're searching for something, do it smart. No full text searches, only indexes etc.

- Check your slow-queries log. Or check your queries with `explain` for this.
- Make sure you're not doing anything with table-locking. Are you using InnoDB? Then you'll have more luck because you get row-level locking.
- Check if you have enough connections available for your server.
- Check you caching settings.

Comment: i m using myisam . and how i can check slow query log.